# Extjs4 add click event to a container and handle it in a controller

Tags: events, extjs4

```
            {xtype : 'container',
        id:'leaderPhotoContainer',
        listeners:{click: {
            element: 'el', //bind to the underlying el property on the panel
            fn: function(e,panel,obj){ //click function
            console.log('click el'); //It will work.
            obj.fireEvent('click');
```

//if I adding my code here ,it is worked ,but I want to fire this event to the controller ,and be handled there.

//How I can get the 'container' here ?
        //container.fireEvent('click') I guess it will work.

```
}
                }}}
```

Can someone help me? Thank you.

```
listeners:{click: {
            element: 'el', //bind to the underlying el property on the panel
            fn: function(e,panel,obj){ console.log('click el');
            this.down('#leaderPhotoContainer').fireEvent('click');
            }
            ,scope:this//It must be a upper container.
            }
```

Maybe It is a silly way to slove it,but It is worked . Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind your event in your controller.

```
//...
init: function () {
    this.control({
        'yourpanel': {
            afterrender: function(panel) {
                panel.mon(panel.el, 'click', this.foo);
            }
        }
    });
},

foo: function() {
    console.log('Foo');
}
//...
```

Comment: Just used this works great. But useful to note that you can also pass arguments through to the event using [options] in function format `mon(item, ename, [fn], [scope], [options])`